# Run NUnit test case with Admin Privileges

Tags: c#, nunit

I have an NUnit test case that modifies the registry key values. That requires admin privileges.

How to run a particular test case or the whole NUnit project with Admin privileges?
I tried adding app.manifest to NUnit project with below setting, but it didn't work.

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

**Edit**:
I need admin privileges for my unittest because, in my unittest I am trying to edit a reg key. When I am doing it without Admin privileges, I am getting security exception.

```
RegistryKey overrides = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Policies\\Microsoft\\<key>", true);
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550243/how-to-unit-test-administrator-only-functionality and this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d47c32c2-2618-451b-9cfb-542a5454ac21/running-tests-requires-admin-privileges?forum=vststest

Comment: @MaythamFahmi, the SO link above talks about mocking and my scenario is little different. Edited the question to add more details. Also, any idea if app.manifest works for NUnit projects too?

Comment: IMHO Don't. If your test relies on this key, your code is wrong and should be refactored. As much as possible, automated tests should not depend on the OS environment. That's an integration test, not a unit test, and maybe you just can't automate it.

Answer (score 0):

Tests should not permanently affect your environment, thus you should mock the usage of the registry instead of modifying it from your test.

If you still would like to run your tests as an administrator, you probably should divide your test set into two parts:

- one, that does not require elevated privileges
- second, that requires elevated privileges - you can achieve that by executing test runner as administrator

[Category property](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/category.html) should help you to set up those two test sets.